# Is there a way to retrieve an error ID for IOException thrown due to file access being blocked by Windows Defender?

Tags: c#, ioexception, virus

I'm trying to access files in my `Download` folder and want to differentiate possible errors to better inform the user in case something went wrong, especially when `Windows Defender` interfers (see below).

My code looks basically like this:

```
try
{
    fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    if (ex != null && ex.Message.IndexOf("virus", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
    {
        myDataObject.ScanStatus = ScanStatusInfo.NotAccessable;
        throw;
    }
}
```

The string comparison of the exception's message is my dirty workaround for `Windows Defender` intercepting access to a potentially infected file (you can test it with e.g. [eicar test virus](https://www.eicar.org/?page_id=3950)). I'd like to use a different (ID based) approach to handle such cases and not rely on the actual message string.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my approach as follows, based on information from [hresult.info](https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_WIN32/0x800700E1)

```
const uint ERROR_VIRUS_INFECTED = 0X800700E1;

[...]

try
{
    fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    // This handles the case that Windows Defender stopped access to the file due to a virus.
    // If this is the case, we won't get any access and throw the exception instead.
    if (ex != null && (0xFFFF & ex.HResult) == (0XFFFF & ERROR_VIRUS_INFECTED))
    {
        myDataObject.ScanStatus = ScanStatusInfo.NotAccessable;
        throw;
    }
}
```

So this will inform the user about the case described in the question, giving more information than "somehow I couldn't access the file and I don't know why" and also allowing to handle it independently from the system's local language.